# Can Sitecore insert options conditionally add a template based on what the parent item is?

Tags: c#, configuration, sitecore

Say I have the following

```
+Parent A
 -Item One (base template only)
 -Item Two (base template only)
```

Is there a way to configure sitecore insert options to apply a secondary template if "Parent B" is the parent instead of "Parent A"?

```
+Parent B
 -Item One (base template + secondary template)
 -Item Two (base template + secondary template)
```

I hope that is clear -- still relatively new to Sitecore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good question because there are lots of ways to approach this. The recommended best practice is to add "Insert Options Rules" which are found at the following location in the content tree: /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules.

Insert Option Rules are great because they are manageable through Sitecore and offer a lot of flexibility with all the rules that are available. For example, in your case you could create a rule that adds the secondary template as an insert option if the item's parent is "Parent B". There are lots of rules so go through them and figure out what works best for your scenario.